# How can I send my app data from one iPhone to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I built an app which I can add images and texts, what I would like to do is to pack a data from this app (which I can do that by serializing an object to a file) and send it non-synchronically to another app in another IPhone and open it there (without using the mail nor the internet).

for example if I had MMS on IPhone I could do that by sending the file as MMS and set my app to open files with specific post-fix I choose.

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to send the data to another app on the same device?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "without using the internet"? You could use NSNetServices to establish connections between devices, and send whatever you want between them. This relies on the TCP/IP protocol though, but does not use HTTP. So if you mean "without going via HTTP", this should be an alternative:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/ResolvingServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001078-SW1

Answer (score 0):

you use an url scheme for small data, or the new UIDocumentInteractionController